# mongo command writes to standard output AND pipe

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongodb-query

I can't write my head around the fact that the mongo command still display results on standard output, when the command is piped:

```
mongo --quiet  localhost:7017/admin -u $mongo_rootuser -p $mongo_rootpw --eval "JSON.stringify(db.getUsers())" | <whatever command processes the output>
```

I should not see anything printed on my console, since the result of the command is piped.

Please, any workaround?
(apart from asking mongo devs to respect basic posix)

Comment: You may be seeing errors which are output to fd 2 as opposed to 1

Comment: No, it's regular output of the command (mongo returning me users in this case)

Comment: Add complete output to question and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for disturbing, I managed to find a workaround, can still be useful to others.

I put the mongo command in a variable:

```
result=$(mongo --quiet  localhost:7017/admin -u $mongo_rootuser -p $mongo_rootpw --eval "JSON.stringify(db.getUsers())")
echo $result | <whatever command>
```

NB: this problem is addressed in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23810 without workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You are not capturing STDOUT with a pipe - you are just using the result of your command. Re-route the entire output to wherever you want it to be and from there you can do something with it - but be aware it also gives you all erros and the complete response:

```
mongo --quiet  localhost:7017/admin -u $mongo_rootuser -p $mongo_rootpw --eval "JSON.stringify(db.getUsers())" >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1

grep /var/log/whatever.log | <whatever command>
```

Comment: I don't want to use a temporary file.

Comment: The problem is that imho you are not making clear what you want and why not using a temporary file - I mean how do you want to differentiate between STDERR and STDOUT.

Comment: Thing is, when using `--eval`, mongo still prints out stuff, even though the output should be piped. What is printed out is not STDERR, it's just the regular output.

It's like if you did `ls -lh | <whatever command>`, the output was piped AND displayed. Not expected